# ons-toolbarにmodifierでtransparentを設定しても反映されない

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

[ons-toolbar](http://ja.onsen.io/reference/ons-toolbar.html#modifiers)

ons-toolbarにて以下のようにmodifierを設定しています。

```
<ons-toolbar modifier="transparent"> ... </ons-toolbar>
```

ところが反映されません。書き方に問題があると思いますが、サンプルを読んでもこれ以上は読み取れませんでした。

どのように記載するのが正しいのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`modifier`属性の書き方は合っています。jsおよびcssが正しく読み込まれているか、jsで何らかのエラーが出ていないか等、コンソールを開いて確認してみてください。閉じタグのtypoも気になるところです。それでもダメでしたら、コードの全体を載せていただくと解決が早いと思います。

公式のtoolbarサンプルを載せておきますので、ご自分のコードと照らしあわせてみてください。
http://codepen.io/onsen/pen/aHmGL

Comment: 公式では、何も読み込ませてないんですよね。onsenuiだけだと思います。閉じ方のミスはタイプミスなので修正しました。

Comment: modifierにtransparentを指定した際のスタイリングはonsen-css-components.cssというファイルに書かれています。このファイルは正しく読み込まれていますか？

Comment: loader.cssを確認したら書き込まれていませんでした。loader.cssに

`@import url("monaca-onsenui/css/onsen-css-components.css");`

を追記して再読込させましたが、反映されませんでした。

Comment: MonacaIDEをお使いでしたら、新規プロジェクトとして「OnsenUI 最小限のテンプレート」を作成して、toolbarのmodifier属性を指定して正常に機能することを確認してみてください。そこから少しづつ改変してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: 原因がわかりました。ons-toolbarの透過はすでに行われていましたが、その下のレイヤーに配置したつもりのCarouselが、そう言うふうに配置されておらず、全画面表示されていないと言うことが問題でした。お手数おかけしました。Carouselをどうすれば全画面表示されるのかが次の課題というか、普通にdivでCarouselの上に配置するしか無いかもしれません。

やりたかったこと
一番上　transparentしたons-toolbar
真ん中　ons-carousel
一番下　ons-page 

現状

同列に　transparentしたons-toolbar | ons-carousel
一番下　ons-page

やり方的にはdivでabsoluteみたいなもので固定で縛ってしまうしか無いのかもしれません。（carouselの上に載せるために）

Comment: toolbarを使用すると、`.page__content`にデフォルトで`top: 44px`が指定されます。`style.css`に`ons-toolbar ~ .page__content{top: 0;}`を書けば直ると思います。

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26849/discussion-between-cither-and-masahiro-kawai)しましょう。